# Google analytics lost conversions after implementing social login

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, google-ads

we have recently implemented social login to our website. We are running ads to that website and after implementing the social login we lost all conversion data - everything is accounted to facebook.

Also we have kind of "sub-website" shop-domain.com where are some products that are sold separately and user can migrate between domain.com and shop-domain.com and vice versa. Can this loose conversions as well?

My question is:

how can we configure analytics / ads / website to correctly count the conversions?

What have I done:

In google analytics documentation I found something called linker to fix user migration between domains and page referrer after login. But it doesnt seem to help

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {
        'linker': {
            'domains': ['domain.com', 'domain.eu', 'shop-domain.com', 'shop-domain.eu']
        },
        'page_referrer':'domain.com'
    });
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics tracks users using cookies. You can share the cookie within your domains or subdomains using the same code but not with external domains (Facebook), that's why it is not working for you.

A user that uses social login will become a referral from this social network so you need to [add those domains to the referral exclusion list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).

> By default, a referral automatically triggers a new session. When you
>   exclude a referral source, traffic that arrives to your site from the
>   excluded domain doesn’t trigger a new session. If you want traffic
>   arriving from a specific site to trigger a new session, don't include
>   that domain in this table.

In addition to all of this, you can implement the Analytics [User-Id function](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) to make sure you track all the user's conversion path.

> User-ID enables the association of one or more sessions (and the
>   activity within those sessions) with a unique and persistent ID that
>   you send to Analytics.
>
> To implement User-ID, you must be able to generate your own unique
>   IDs, consistently assign IDs to users, and include these IDs wherever
>   you send data to Analytics.

Comment: When I check _ga, _gid, _gcl_aw cookies before / after login they are the same

Comment: @Emirodgar  What happens to traffic from those social networks that is actual referral traffic? 
If the social networks are added to the referral exclusion list, then legit referral traffic from those networks will appear as direct/none for the ones added to the list. 
Would a viable alternative be to use htaccess or another method to append utm parameters assigning direct/none as the source/medium to the social login's return to site url?

Comment: Nice question. Normally, they used different subdomains for social login than referral traffic, so you can exclude only those related to the login process. If that was not possible, I can't think of another way with Analytics so you will be right and would be needed extra help through .htaccess file (mapping traffic source as a custom campaing or direct/none) and avoiding the exclude.

Comment: You can't just add facebook to your referral exclusion list because they send actual referrers as well.  You can do so for google because the social login uses `accounts.google.com` as the referrer.